# How can I send a Notification via Firebase Cloud Messaging from a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

The documentation at
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.md#getmessaging
does not explain where the "firebase-admin/messaging" module is. What is the require path to get this module?

for instance

```
const { getMessaging } = require("firebase-admin/messaging");
```

does not work.

I also looked into the cloud functions sdk at  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions#functions.pubsub where I see the Message class but no way to send a message.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it:

```
const messaging = admin.messaging();
```

which means that the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?authuser=0 is outdated.